# Form validation fails due missing CSRF

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

A few days ago I have reset my local flask environment without having captured the dependencies via a `pip freeze` before I deleted it.  Hence I had to re-install the latest version of the entire stack.

Now out of the blue I am no longer able to validate with forms. Flask claims CSRF would be missing.

```
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       ...
    return make_response("register.html", form=form, error=form.errors)
```

The first time I send a `Get` I retrieve an empty `form.errors` as expected.
Now I fill out the form and submit it and `form.errors` is showing: `{'csrf_token': [u'CSRF token missing']}`

This is so strange. I wonder if Flask-WTF has changed and I am using it wrongly.

I can clearly see the `form.CSRF_token` exists, so why is it claiming it was missing?

```
CSRFTokenField: <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1391278044.35##3f90ec8062a9e91707e70c2edb919f7e8236ddb5">
```

I never touched the working template, but I post it here nonetheless:

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div class="center simpleform">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    {% if error %}<p class=error><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}{% endif %}
    <form class="form-signin" action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method=post>
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        <dl>
            {{ render_field(form.name) }}
            {{ render_field(form.email) }}
            {{ render_field(form.password) }}
            {{ render_field(form.confirm) }}
            <dd><input type=submit value=Register class='btn btn-primary'>
        </dl>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Is this a new bug?

**UPDATE:**

I have reinstalled everything and the problem persists.

As Martijn suggested, I am debugging into the the following method in `flask_wtf` :

```
def validate_csrf_token(self, field):
        if not self.csrf_enabled:
            return True
        if hasattr(request, 'csrf_valid') and request.csrf_valid:
            # this is validated by CsrfProtect
            return True
        if not validate_csrf(field.data, self.SECRET_KEY, self.TIME_LIMIT):
            raise ValidationError(field.gettext('CSRF token missing'))
```

The last condition is raising the validation error.

```
field.data = "1391296243.8##1b02e325eb0cd0c15436d0384f981f06c06147ec"
self.SECRET_KEY = None (? Is this the problem)
self.TIME_LIMIT = 3600
```

And you were right the HMAC comparison fails....both values are in every time different.

```
return hmac_compare == hmac_csrf
```

I have both SECRET_KEY and CSRF_SESSION_KEY in my config defined.

Comment: Are you accepting cookies? The CSRF architecture requires that the `csrf_token` value is present in the session and valid; it is a random value used to sign the token and on posting it is used to verify the CSRF token with the form (together with the server-side secret).

Comment: Yes, Neither Firefox nor Chrome are blocking cookies.  I don't understand.

Comment: So, to verify, you do see the a cookie named `session` set (provided you didn't set `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` to something else)?

Comment: Yes. In Eclipse under Debug Watchlist, when I enter `session`, I get this: `LocalProxy: <SecureCookieSession {'csrf_token': '2182effc89ce180a53622272d88d4466679920cd'}>`

Comment: The other failure mode is that the cookie is too old, but I suspect you didn't leave it as long as the default 1 hour expiration.

Comment: If you know how to debug (with PDB or a remote debugger), open up `flask_wtf.csrf` and put a breakpoint in `validate_csrf` to see why the token is being rejected.

Comment: Right, I posted your debugging options in my answer below.

Comment: `self.SECRET_KEY` is a per form secret key, it can safely be left at `None` at which point the `app.config['WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY']` value is used (which defaults to `app.secret_key`).

Comment: I was having this issue for a long time, realized it was my `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True` application setting. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: If you happen to use **FieldSets**, you should put hidden_tag into each, and also into the main form. That's probably because each FieldSet is evaluated separately.
Also keep in mind the Troubleshooting notice below [Flask-WTF CSRF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html) description, and import Form class from flask.ext.wtf insted of wtforms!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Flask-WTF CSRF infrastructure rejects a token if:

- the token is missing. Not the case here, you can see the token in the form.
- it is too old (default expiration is set to 3600 seconds, or an hour). Set the `TIME_LIMIT` attribute on forms to override this. Probably not the case here.
- if no `'csrf_token'` key is found in the current session. You can apparently see the session token, so that's out too.
- If the HMAC signature doesn't match; the signature is based on the random value set in the session under the `'csrf_token'` key, the server-side secret, and the expiry timestamp in the token.

Having eliminated the first three possibilities, you need to verify why the 4th step fails. You can debug the validation in `flask_wtf/csrf.py` file, in the `validate_csrf()` function.

For your setup, you need to verify that the session setup is correct (especially if you don't use the default session configuration), and that you are using the correct server-side secret. The form itself could have a `SECRET_KEY` attribute set but is not stable across requests, or the app `WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY` key has changed (the latter defaults to the [`app.secret_key` value](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.secret_key)).

The CSRF support was added in version 0.9.0, do check out the specific [CSRF protection documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html) if you upgraded. The standard Flask-WTF `Form` class *includes* the CSRF token as a hidden field, rendering the hidden fields is enough to include it:

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, your help is really appreciated.  May you please have a look at my updated question?

Comment: In my case, the app was working fine on local machine but it crashed while hosting. This was due to incorrect session setting as described by the author.
Please set a constant secret key in flask app if you're running into same problem.

Answer (score 18):

I finally found the problem after nearly a day working on it. :( 
Big thanks to Martijn though for his help.

The actual problem lies in the way the latest `flask_wtf.csrf` is working. The makers have overhauled it completely.

You have to replace all `{{form.hidden_tag()}}` in your templates with 
`<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>`.

And you have now to enable CSRF protection explicitly by adding `CsrfProtect(app)`.

The [documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-flask_wtf.csrf) is now obviously reflecting that, but I didn't know this has changed and was chasing ghosts.

Its a big problem with deprecated functionality without notifying the developer somehow. Anyone that upgrades now to the latest version, will be chasing ghosts like I did. But its also my fault not having taken a snapshot of my dependencies. Lesson learned the hard way.

Comment: You don't have to replace the `hidden_tag()`, but the `CsrfProtect(app)` is certainly required.

Comment: Also, `self.SECRET_KEY` is the per-form secret, when it is set to `None`, the app secret is used.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I found another issue. I am deploying it on GAE. It seems `flask_wtf` is colliding with `Flask-DebugToolbar`. When I disable `toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)`, CSRF is working on developer environment. But only those developers are affected that are using `flask-appengine-template`. :)

Comment: Interesting. My current project is using Flask on GAE, but I didn't use any templates, nor use Flask-DebugToolbar. If I do, I'll watch out for any issues.

Comment: I was having the same issue. adding `WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY` solved the problem.

Comment: os.urandom() is bad idea for SECRET_KEY generation when using gunicorn with workers greater than 1

Comment: I now have several projects with both the debug toolbar and CSRF protected forms. If you are only using FlaskForm forms, CSRFProtect is not needed *at all* and all you need in a template is the `form.hidden_tag()` output.  Put differently; you only need to use `"{{ csrf_token() }}` and CSRFProtect for views that do not use a FlaskForm form object!

Comment: Instead of `CsrfProtect(app)` you can use lazy loading with `csrf = CsrfProtect() csrf.init_app(app)`.

Comment: doesn't work for me :/

Answer (score 6):

At the time of creating the app:

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect

csrf = CsrfProtect()

app = Flask(__name__)   

...

csrf.init_app(app)

...
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was not coming from Flask-WTF being badly configured, or a missing token. It was coming **from the environment variables**.

If your Flask server is not running on localhost then in order to get Flask to work properly, you need to set a `SERVER_NAME` environment variable. You’ve likely forgotten to modify the `SERVER_NAME` value somewhere.

For example, you could have something like this in `config/settings.py`:

```
SERVER_NAME = 'my-domain.com'
```

For more information, check out [this great resource](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/fix-missing-csrf-token-issues-with-flask)

Answer (score 2):

## Using FieldLists?

When using `FieldList`, there is another source of the error that unfortunately, I found after hours of debugging:

```
class Subform(FlaskForm):
    """Parent form."""
    text = StringField("Text")


class Maniform(FlaskForm):
    """Parent form."""
    laps = FieldList(
        FormField(Subform),
        min_entries=1,
        max_entries=30
    )
```

This will not handle the CSRF correctly because `Subform` should inherit from `wtforms.Form`

```
class Subform(Form):
    """Parent form."""
    text = StringField("Text")
```

Fixing this bug solved my problems.

Comment: I was looking just for this. Every other forms were working fine, except the one implemented using FieldList. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As you said hours of debugging and searching, now I know and wrote a comment in my app!

Answer (score 2):

It's a little different than you. In my case, it was simply because I had `{{ form.csrf_token }}` before the form tag.

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
<form class="container" method="POST" id="form"> ... </form>
```

So I put it in the form tag

```
<form class="container" method="POST" id="form"> {{ form.csrf_token }} </form>
```

and that's it !

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue because I used a hyphen instead of an underscore for the element name.

```html
<!-- Wrong -->
<input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

<!-- Correct -->
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

For non-WTForms, I guess the CSRF extension looks through the DOM for an element with name: '**csrf_token**' not '**csrf-token**'.

This is an error that anyone could easily make. In one of my other templates, I changed the input name to include a hyphen because I was sending the formData with Fetch API. I unknowingly copied the same input tag and that was what led to the error.

This means that the name attribute value could be anything as long as one is responsible for sending the token value to the backend themselves. But if you want the *flask_wtf.CSRF* extension to implicitly protect your *non-WTForm*, you have to do it the way it's expected:

```html
<input name="csrf_token"/>
```

If you're still experiencing CSRF issues in Flask, I'll refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72126425/16792256) great SO answer.