# WTforms IntegerField in fieldlist never validates using manual iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have an `InterField`, that validates if a number is between the values `0` and `99`. For some reason it never validates. 
I have a feeling it is related to the `FieldList` and ther way I iterate over it in the template, but can't seem to get it working.

The form:

```
class dpiaImpactAnalysisForm(Form):

    severity_score = IntegerField("Severity Score"), 
        validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=99, message="Please provide a valid number")]))
    identifiability_score = IntegerField("Identifiability Score"),
        validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=99, message="Please provide a valid number")]))


class dpiaThreatAnalysisForm(Form):

    impact = FieldList(FormField(dpiaImpactAnalysisForm), min_entries=1)
```

In views I append the entries dynamically as required:

```
@app.route('/dpia/analysis/<project_id>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def analysis(project_id):

    form = dpiaThreatAnalysisForm()

    prim = Assets.query.filter_by(selected=True, primary=True).all()
    primary_assets = list(map(vars, prim))

    ev = Events.query.all()
    events = list(map(vars, ev))

    # add fields to the form...
    for z in range(len(prim) * len(ev)):
        form.impact.append_entry()

    supp = Assets.query.filter_by(selected=True, primary=False).all()
    supporting_assets = list(map(vars, supp))

    ths = Threats.query.all()
    threats = list(map(vars, ths))

    # add fields to the form
    for z in range(len(ths) * len(supp)):
        form.likelihood.append_entry()

    if form.is_submitted():
        print "submitted"
    if form.validate():
        print "valid"
    print form.errors

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # This is never printed:
        app.logger.info("success!!")
        pprint(form.likelihood)

    return redirect(url_for(next_step, project_id=project_id))
return render_template('analysis.html', form=form, threats=threats, supporting_assets=supporting_assets, primary_assets=primary_assets, events=events)
```

In the template I iterate over a list `primary_assets` in a list `events`, and add the fields per iteration:

```
{% for val in events %}
   {% if not counter or loop.index0 == 0 %}
      {% set counter = [] %}  <!-- loop hack !-->
   {% endif %}
   <strong>Event: {{ val.name }}</strong><br />
   Jeopardizes: {{ val.jeopardizes }}<br />

   {% for pa in primary_assets %}
       <strong>{{ pa['name'] }}</strong><br />
       {{ form.impact[counter|length].identifiability_score(placeholder='') }} <br />
       {{ form.impact[counter|length].severity_score(placeholder='') }} 
       {{ form.impact[counter|length].hidden_tag() }} 
       {% if counter.append('1') %}{% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `hidden_tag()` doesn't work either. Normally I iterate of the forms with with something like

```
 {% for impact in form.impact %}
     {{ impact.form.hidden_tag() }}
     # do cbg
  {% endfor %}
```

and that works, that's why I believe it's my manual looping that spoils it...

**EDIT 2 march, 17:26**

After some testing, I found that using

`severity_score = IntegerField("Severity Score", validators=[Optional(), NumberRange(
        min=0, max=9999999999, message="Please provide a valid number")])`

works (if I set `min=50` I get an error when inserting a number below 50), however, the CSRF is still not getting passed.

`{{ form.impact[counter|length].hidden_tag() }}` or 
`{{ form.impact[counter|length].form.hidden_tag() }}` both don't work :(

I'm getting: `{'impact': [{'csrf_token': ['CSRF token missing']}, {'csrf_token': ['CSRF token missing']}]}`

*EDIT 18:22*

It seems that this: [Form validation fails due missing CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501058/form-validation-fails-due-missing-csrf) is the solution. Investigating...

Comment: What is `form` and what is `bananas`?

Comment: @dirn see edit above. in the for-loop I iterate over the `fieldlist(formfield())`  (`impact` comes from `dpiaThreatAnalysisForm`)

Comment: I was referring to the references in your views. You shared *some* of your code, but a lot of important stuff seems to be missing. You consume variables that are never defined. It's quite possible that `form` isn't being instantiated correctly, but until we see the whole view, it's hard to know.

Comment: @dirn added more view code.

Comment: Do you include the CSRF token in your form?

Comment: The hidden-tag()  takes care of that

Comment: Is `hidden_tag()` actually including it? Are you sure you don't need `form.hidden_tag()` instead of things like `impact.form.hidden_tag()` and `form.impact[...].hidden_tag()`?

Comment: this got fixed by the `CsrfProtect(app)` line, that in previous versions of WTforms wasn't needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: [Form validation fails due missing CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501058/form-validation-fails-due-missing-csrf) is the solution.

In previous versions this wasn't needed, and after an installation of a new extension pip updated flask-wtf as well...