# Flask-WTF CSRFProtect gives "400 The CSRF Token is missing" error

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to add CSRF token protection using Flask-WTF's `CSRFProtect` extension. The app isn't using WTForms except for this CSRF protection.

I followed [the docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html) but I get "400 Bad Request The CSRF token is missing".

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

I put the following in the templates (with form or without a form) but I get the same error.

```html
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21501593/6770522), inspect the actual CSFR validation flow:

> You can debug the validation in
>   `flask_wtf/csrf.py` file, in the `validate_csrf()` function.

For me, the issue was caused by a recent update of *Flask* and *Flask-WTF*. I solved it by removing all the `.pyc` files in the project. However, I don't know the actual root cause in my case.

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

**Later edit:**

- update to latest versions of Flask, Flask-WTF;
- on your development environment, if using HTTP instead of HTTPS, make sure `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` is not set to `True`. See [this](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/issues/76).

Comment: omfg thank you! SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE on HTTP must be turned off