# Flask-WTF FileField fails on validate_on_submit

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to be able to upload a CSV file on Flask using Flask-WTF FileField, but can't get pass the `validate_on_submit` .

This is my view.

```
@main.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_products():

    form = UploadForm()
    print (request.method)
    print (form.validate_on_submit())
    print (form.csv.data)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print ('valid on submit')
        f = form.csv.data
        print (f)
        return redirect(url_for('upload_products'))
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```

this is my form

```
class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    csv = FileField("")
```

this is my `html` file.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="my-4">Hello! Upload files here!</h1>
</div>
<div class="container" >
  <form action="{{ url_for('main.upload_products') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{form.csv}}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

on `validate_on_submit`, I am always receiving a `False` value. 
I also printed out `form.csv.data` and this is the result I got:

```
<FileStorage: '12347.csv' ('application/vnd.ms-excel')>
```

Why is it failing on `validate_on_submit`? Did I miss something?

Comment: I guess it's the CSRF issue. Can you print out the `form.errors`? It should said "CSRF token missing". If so, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21501593/2644759

Comment: you are right, error is `The CSRF token is missing.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding `{{form.hidden_tag()}}` on my template.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="my-4">Hello! Upload files here!</h1>
</div>
<div class="container" >
  <form action="{{ url_for('main.upload_products') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{form.hidden_tag()}}
      {{form.csv}}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```