# Jinja template has no hidden tags and validate_on_submit not working

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to make a weather application..
I am using flask.
I am getting the following error : 
 
`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'forms.WeatherForm object' has no attribute 'hidden_tag'`

My code below: 
Weather.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
        <!-- {{ form.hidden_tag() }} -->
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Place</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.place.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {% if form.place.errors %}
                    {{ form.place(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.place.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ form.place(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
        </div>

    </form>


{% endblock content %}
```

route.py :

```
from flask import (render_template, url_for, flash,
               redirect, request, Flask)
from forms import WeatherForm
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/weather', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def weather():
    form = WeatherForm()
    # if form.validate_on_submit():
    # return redirect('url_for("result")')
    return render_template('weather.html', form=form)


@app.route('/result',methods=['POST'])
def result():
    render_template('result.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have commented the if statement bcz I am getting another error...

`AttributeError: 'WeatherForm' object has no attribute 'validate_on_submit'`

forms.py :

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class WeatherForm():
    place = StringField('Place', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

Not sure if I have not imported some functionalities for the above errors..
I am new to flask... Thanks for the help

Edit : Found another solution..If the csrf does not work, we can set a SECRT_KEY...
[Another answer that helps after my first error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687307/how-do-you-solve-the-error-keyerror-a-secret-key-is-required-to-use-csrf-whe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider implementing `FlaskForm` into your `WeatherForm` as such:

```
class WeatherForm(FlaskForm):
    place = StringField('Place', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

Also, implement [CSRF protection](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html) on the app:

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

# Add this somewhere in your app's initialization
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

Comment: Thanks..That helped..But may I know where exactly to add the csrf?

Comment: Insert it below `app = Flask(__name__)` @Anirudh

Comment: Thanks @Yaakov Bressler

Comment: Also, the form is never valid on submit...What is the mistake in the code??

Comment: Is it possible your `WeatherForm` isn't configured correctly? My assumption is that that is where the responsibility for this error is.