# 'csrf_token': ['The CSRF token is missing.'] >> flask_wtf

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I want to make a registration form using flask_wft 
but this line never executed

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
```

because `form.validate()` return False 
the reason is `csrf_token`.
this is my code:

```
`@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def form():
     form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
     if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
     user = Person(f_name=form.firstName.data,
            l_name=form.lastName.data,
            email=form.email.data,city=form.city.data)
     db.session.add(user)
     db.session.commit()
     return redirect(url_for('welcome'))
 print('errors: '+ str(form.errors))
 return render_template('form.html', form=form)`
```

I got this error: `'csrf_token': ['The CSRF token is missing.']`

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have `{{ form.hidden_tag }}` in your form ?

Comment: Yes, I do below form tag

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501058/form-validation-fails-due-missing-csrf

Comment: Did you tried inspecting the form html to see if the csrf token is present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just put this line `{{ form.csrf_token() }}` under 'form' tag

the Best Answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501058/form-validation-fails-due-missing-csrf)

for more info: https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.12/csrf.html